# What is the correct usage? "Ever so often" or "Every so often"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

A colleague asked to check in with me every couple of weeks. I would like to respond that it would be wonderful if they checked in ever so often. But, I don't believe that sounds correct. How should I phrase it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Ever so* is a rather archaic way of indicating degree, as in "I like picnics *ever so* much!" It is something you might hear Dorothy say to the Scarecrow in *The Wizard of Oz*.

If you hear it used to mean *every so*, the speaker is probably dropping the *-y* from the end of *every*. What you're hearing is probably:

> It'd be wonderful if they checked in
>   ever' so often.

I've heard the *-y* elided in this way in the southern and western regions of the U.S.

Comment: I liked this answer best of the three that are here (as of this writing), because it strikes a nice balance between brevity and information.

Comment: FWIW "Ever so" isn't archaic in the UK :-)

Answer (score 6):

#### *ever so often*

The phrase *ever so* simply means *very*. When used with *often*, it emphasizes the frequency slightly more than *very* does. Compare:

- ```
  "He checked in very often."
  ```
- ```
  "He checked in ever so often."
  ```

In the second example, the speaker subtly indicates his/her slight irritation or delight in the fact that "he" visited/called/stopped by to see the speaker so frequently.

#### *every so often*

This phrase means *occasionally*. It can be easily substituted with *from time to time*, *sometimes* or *every now and then*. Examples:

- ```
  He takes a trip to London every so often.
  ```
- ```
  I wish I could see him every day, not just every so often.
  ```

*Every so often* is more commonly used, I think, though I have this hunch that the meaning is sometimes confused with *very often*, which is just the opposite. Your sentence probably did not sound correct to your ears because one rarely hears *ever so often* these days, save in literary and poetic contexts. To analyze your response a bit further:

- If you are happy with the frequency of a fortnightly check-in, then I think the proper response should be:

```
It would be wonderful if you checked in every so often.
```

- If, perhaps, you would prefer a more regular check-in (say, every couple days, for instance), then you might respond thus:

```
That's great, but it would be wonderful if you checked in ever so often.
```

Honestly, since your chief aim is to communicate, I would suggest you avoid ambiguity. Hence, I would recommend using *every so often* or, better, another adverb that clearly expresses your thoughts.

NB: I confirmed my definitions with the New Oxford American Dictionary, 2nd Edition (installed on my mac) and the [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/every_2).

Comment: Your example “That's great, but it would be wonderful if you checked in ever so often.” does not seem idiomatic to me: *ever so* is not an exact synonym of *very*, but also carries a connotation of *especially* or *remarkably*, which does not fit in this context.

Comment: I do agree *ever so* is not an exact synonym of *very* and I alluded to this point earlier on in my answer. I was trying quite hard to justify the asker's use of *ever so often* and I guess I didn't hit the spot. I'll think over this a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

"Every so often" is the correct phrasing.